# Unable to decompile C Code

Tags: ida, decompilation

Recently, i have gone through some kind of win32-64 executable files which can't be decompiled under IDA (into Pseudocode). Only the Assembly Code can be read. When i try to press F5 to decompile the file,it only shows me a Diaglog Box says "Positive Stack Value found".The Debugging process is still fine.It's just i can't not decompile the file into c source code.

I wonder how can they do that? I mean they can make the executable unable to decompile under IDA or maybe other Disassembler.

I want to accomplish this using other compilers such as GCC,MinGW,Clang,or even Turbo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you encounter this kind of error, just make sure that the stack pointer is aligned.

[image]

Go to Options tab.

[image]

Click General...

[image]

Click the Stack Pointer.

It will show the stack pointers at the left side.
[image]

[image]

Click the sub esp, 0x15c, press Alt+k, then click OK.

[image]

So it must be able to solve your problem.

[image]

Press F5.

[image]